# Insert multiple Insert statements into one table row

Tags: php, sql

I think it should be possible, but i dont have a clue how to write it.

- 1st statement: Select multiple data from table1 and copy them to table2.
- 2nd statement: Save a variable to table2.

both statements should be saved in the same table row.

here is my code:

```
foreach($_POST["checkbox"] as $id){

            $query ="INSERT INTO table2 (name, number, price, quantity, sumPrice, supplier, customer)
                    SELECT name, number, price, quantity, sumPrice, supplier, customer
                    FROM table1
                    WHERE table1_id = '".$id."'";

                    "INSERT INTO table2(adoptedBy)
                    VALUES ('$name')";

            $result = mysqli_query($db_link, $query);
```

what did i wrong?

Comment: what does $_POST["checkbox"] return?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table2  SELECT name, number, price, quantity, sumPrice, supplier, customer FROM table1 WHERE table1_id=`

Comment: what does  `$name` contain?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile How would that solve his problem?

Comment: @Hienz if that `$name` is null and the db is set not to be null for adobtedby will cause problems

Comment: @Yosshi you have answers below please examine them and comment on them

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile $name ist the username from the actual session. it shouldnt be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1st statement: Select multiple data from table1 and copy them to
>   table2.

You will need to use [**INSERT INTO SELECT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)  which you did well.

```
$query ="INSERT INTO table2 (name, `number`, price, quantity, sumPrice, supplier, customer)
                    SELECT name, `number`, price, quantity, sumPrice, supplier, customer
                    FROM table1
                    WHERE table1_id = '".$id."'";
```

> 2nd statement: Save a variable to table2.

One thing you did not notice is that after `WHERE table1_id = '".$id."'";` you terminated `$query`  therefore this never runs `

```
"INSERT INTO table2(adoptedBy)
                    VALUES ('$name')";
```

what you can do is to use [mysqli_multi_query();](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Then you query will be something like :

```
 <?php

    $query = "INSERT INTO table2 (name, `number`, price, quantity, sumPrice, supplier, customer)
                    SELECT name, `number`, price, quantity, sumPrice, supplier, customer
                    FROM table1
                    WHERE table1_id = '" . $id . "';";

    $query .= "UPDATE table2 SET adoptedBy =".$name."  where id =  LAST_INSERT_ID()";

    $result = mysqli_multi_query($db_link, $query);


    if ($result) {

        echo "success";
    } else {

        echo "Error : " . mysqli_error($db_link);
    }

?>
```

Hope this helps.

> NB: I advice that you start learning doing sql queries [using prepared
>   statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) whether you are using [mysqli prepared](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [pdo
>   prepared](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) statements

Edit :

Alternative when the above suggestion does not work,

You may update the [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html) when the first query run successfully get that last inserted id then do an update on that id

```
<?php


    $query = "INSERT INTO table2 (name, `number`, price, quantity, sumPrice, supplier, customer)
                    SELECT name, `number`, price, quantity, sumPrice, supplier, customer
                    FROM table1
                    WHERE table1_id = '" . $id . "';";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_link, $query);


    if ($result) {

        $query = "UPDATE table2 SET adoptedBy ='".$name."' WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();";
        if(mysqli_query($db_link,$query)){

            echo "success";
        }else{

            echo "update failed".mysqli_error($db_link);
        }
    } else {

        echo "Error : " . mysqli_error($db_link);
    }

?>
```

Comment: doesnt this just overwrite the first query?

Comment: No there's a concatenation sign for `$query` in your case the second statement never execute this solves that

Comment: yea i get an error, but a blank one without any info

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? That is impossible how can an error be blank, check server log and enable error reporting

Comment: the error from your if statement is blank.
Errorr reporting is on E_ALL
and the last entry from the xampp error log is from 09:14 am.

Comment: add this `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` at the top before connection.. then tell m what u get

Comment: edit: ok maybe i have some trouble with a second query. got an sql syntax error after commenting the 2nd one!.
$query2 ="DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = '".$id."'";    $result2 = mysqli_query($db_link, $query2);

Comment: You did not have any delete and `$query2` on your OP

Comment: Heres the error: Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE table2 SET adoptedBy =testwhere id = LAST_INSER' at line 4

Comment: And yea, didnt thought that this would be neccessary

Comment: `adoptedBy =testwhere id` there must be a space between where an test

Comment: Edited my answer check and run again

Comment: @Yosshi please see the revised edit tested and works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Meh.. If you need explanation, there you go. 
You mentioned, that you want to insert a single row and then update it. Since the INSERT statement is inserting a new row to the table (self-explained..), you need to use an UPDATE statement, which updates a specific row with new values.

So you'll first insert a new row with INSERT and then update the 'adoptedBy' field with your new value.

Example:

```
"UPDATE table2 SET adoptedBy='$name' WHERE --Here you refer to the row's primary id";
```

After the WHERE clause you just identify somehow your row (e.g. primary ID, which is not shown in the OP)

Comment: An example would be better

Comment: or a comment if u don't have an example

Comment: you can not do that using single query

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: Give him a chance to represent him @Hienz your answer should be descriptive with proper explanations and example.

Comment: The OP used SQL properly, he just probably didn't think of the UPDATE statement, that's why I didn't explain it that much. But as u wish guys, there you go, hope it's fine.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot first, yeah an update makes sense. but how do i identify the row? the table id is named "id"  with auto increment.